# Как сделать чтобы значения переменных сохранялись после завершения работы программы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, переменные

В игре я сделал систему достижений, и она определяет получил ли достижение игрок по переменным.
Когда игрок получает достижение, переменная меняется на `1`.
Когда игра видит что переменная равна одному, она выводит, что достижение получено. Это работает, но так как в начале я указал, что переменная равна нулю, она и равна нулю, и после перезапуска игра видит, переменная равна нулю, и выводит что у игрока нету достижения.
Помогите пожалуйста, как сделать так чтобы значения сохранялись?

```
if ach1 == 0: # Тут проверяется есть ли у игрока достижение. Если ach1 не равен нулю, значит есть
        ach_1 = Button(achiv, text='Достижение не разблокировано')
        ach_1.place(x=1, y=0, width=450, height=50)
    else:
        ach_1 = Button(achiv, text='Достижение разблокировано')
        ach_1.place(x=1, y=0, width=450, height=50)
...
    def clicked(): # А вот тут достижение игрок получает.
        global ach1
        if code == '12345':
            ach1 = 1
...
```

Comment: Нужно использовать базу данных

Comment: При выходе/при сохранении игры необходимо записывать параметры пользователя где-либо например в файле (для не онлайн игры). Видел что создают вот по этому пути C:\Users\user\Documents\. Файл может представлять собой json, или какой вам удобнее формат, его даже можно зашифровать. При запуске игры соответственно считывать.

Answer (score 1):

Определите где хотите хранить состояние. На первоначальном этапе и тестировании функционала можете использовать файл и записывать в него. При старте игры читать файл и устанавливать эти состояния.

В дальнейшем используйте базу данных, где хранить все сущности, связанные с игрой

#### UPD

Сразу замечание по вашему коду, не используйте глобальных переменных. Контролировать их - сущий ад.

Покажу пример на основе ООП.

Пишите класс

```py
class Gamer:
  def __init__(self, name, ach1=0):
    self.name = name
    self.ach1 = ach1

  def set_ach1(self):
    self.ach1 = 1

# общая функция сохранения в файл, также может быть и методом класса
import json

def save_ach1s(name, ach1):
  with open("ach1.json", "r") as file:
    ach1s = json.loads(file)
  ach1s[name] = ach1
  with open("ach1.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(ach1s, "ach1.json")
```

Как применять

```py
def clicked(gamer): # А вот тут достижение игрок получает.
   if code == '12345':
       gamer.set_ach1()
       save_ach1s(gamer.name, 1)

gamer = Gamer(name="Pupsik")
clicked(gamer)
```

Я написал вам общую концепцию, чтобы было понятно как организовать запись состояний. Файл в общем виде будет выглядеть так:

```json
{
  "Pupsik":1,
  "ProGamer":1
}
```

Еще раз, откажитесь от глобальных переменных и используйет поля объекта класса для хранения и перезаписи таких значений.

При запуске игры используйте инициализацию объекта и устанавливайте значения из файла. Пример

```py
# start
def create_start_object(name):
  with open("ach1.json", "r") as file:
    ach1s = json.loads(file)
  if ach1s.get(name):
    ach1 = ach1s.get(name)
    gamer = Gamer(name=name, ach1=ach1)
    return gamer
  else:
    gamer = Gamer(name=name)
    return gamer

str_ = input("Введите имя игрока:")
gamer = create_start_object(str_)
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: Это очень сложно сделать в абстрактных понятиях, поскольку возникает ряд вопросов. Покажите релевантный код

Comment: if ach1 == 0: # Тут проверяется есть ли у игрока достижение. Если ach1 не равен нулю, значит есть
        ach_1 = Button(achiv, text='Достижение не разблокировано')
        ach_1.place(x=1, y=0, width=450, height=50)
    else:
        ach_1 = Button(achiv, text='Достижение разблокировано')
        ach_1.place(x=1, y=0, width=450, height=50)
...
    def clicked(): # А вот тут достижение получается
        global ach1
        if code == '12345':
            ach1 = 1
...

Comment: @loganag в сам вопрос добавьте, тут не читабельно совершенно. Для того чтобы это сделать воспользуйтесь ссылкой [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1460597/edit) под самим вопросом